# Error kile 3 beta on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: errors, kile

I've installed the new `kile 3 beta` (on `ubuntu`) but now it shows this problem:

> [Kile] Unknown tool preview-PDFLaTeX..

How can i fix it or downgrade `kile` from 3 beta to 2.1?

Comment: While fixing this problem is `TeX` related, downgrading could be asked on `askubuntu`. If you want to purge and install again with `apt-get`, maybe it's better to move your question to that website.

Comment: You're probably right. Sorry